# ASP.NET MVC6 References in VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using ASP.NET beta 7, VS 2015 on Windows 7.

When I create a new MVC6 project in VS2015 targeting .NET 4.6 framework, my project references look like this:

```
DNX 4.5.1
DNX Core 5.0
```

On some online tutorials I see them as:

```
ASP.NET 5.0
ASP.NET Core 5.0
```

I have tried several online tutorials but am getting errors like:

"...the expected lock file doesn't exist. please run "dnu restore" to generate a new lock file..."

Running "dnu restore" results in pages of errors in command window:

"An error occurred while sending the request"

When I run dnvm, it is showing beta 5... So I tried "dnvm use 1.0.0-beta7" and it still uses beta 5.

I tried "dnvm upgrade" and got following:

[image]

In a particular tutorial I was trying to use MVC6 with EF7 and could not run migration commands.

Can anyone shed some light on any of these issues or point to a good tutorial that actually explains the environment?

Comment: Can u try to using this web tools link? I used this for setup ASP.NET 5 on windows 7, it works like charm https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you need to specify a proxy in order to reach the internet. Both `dnu` and `dnvm` have support for that.

```
dnvm: dnvm upgrade -Proxy ...
dnu: dnu restore --proxy ...
```

Run `dnvm help upgrade` and `dnu restore --help` for more options.

Comment: Thanks I was able to use the dnvm and dnu commands successfully after using the arch and Proxy switches. Can you point me to some info on the reference differences in the project? Either way, marked as answer.